# Как скачать папку с файлами html или js

Tags: javascript, html

Предстоит задачка, необходимо скачать много картинок с сайта по кнопке. Как одну скачать картинку я знаю, а вот нужно скачать все, примерно как скачать html страницу, только без лишнего и чтобы не сильно заморочливо. Возможно через js, если на html нету такого

```
<h3 class="nick-special">Текст</h3>
              <span class="download-special linkontext"> 
              <a href="" class="download-special linkontext" download="./img/special-img/">(скачать все изображения КАК (папкой) ?)</a>

              </span>
        </div>
          <a href="" class="image-special" download="./img/special-img/Изображение"> <img id="img_s" src="./img/special-img/Изображение" alt="">(Тут картинка)</a>
          <a href="" class="image-special" download="./img/special-img/Изображение"> <img id="img_s" src="./img/special-img/Изображение" alt="">(Тут картинка)</a>
          <hr>
          <h3 class="nick-special">Текст</h3>

            </div>
```

Comment: Такая вот "предзагрузка картинок" подойдет? https://only-to-top.ru/blog/coding/2020-03-07-predzagruzka-kartinok.html

Comment: Так это прелоадер, а мне скачать надо )

Comment: Чем отличается твое "скачивание" от "предзагрузки"?

Comment: Мне экспортировать надо на пк, а не на сайте посмотреть )

Comment: Если только сделать апи на сервере, который будет нужные файлы запихивать в архив и отдавать клиенту. Со стороны клиента можно делать множественные запросы, но это потребует разрешения от пользователя.

Comment: Методов несколько. Я попробовал их все и постоянно получил блокировку CORS Policy. Как обойти блокировку не нашел пока, но такое точно возможно, при чем с обычным JS.